# To which cleric(s) does a lay Catholic have to obtain Nihil Obstat and Imprimatur?

Tags: catholicism

For example, a group of lay Catholics are about to publish an app (i.e. a game) that aims to teach Church doctrine. Who must they approach in order to obtain *Nihil Obstat* and an *Imprimatur* to certify that their work has no moral objections from the Roman Catholic Church?

Do they have to submit his/her work to his/her country's episcopal conference? To their company's (or non-profit org's) local diocese? To the [Diocese of San Jose](https://www.dsj.org/) (in reference to the fact that Google's Mountain View Office is located in the Diocese of San Jose)? Does the target user locale determine the authorities that will give the *Nihil Obstat* and the *Imprimatur*? (example: Locale-en-US)

Very much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think they need Nihil Obstat if they only reference Catechism. Is the new app going to contain some new interpretations of the bible or catechism? They will only need Nihil Obstat if the app will claim the official teaching of the Catholic Church. http://www.cuf.org/2006/03/nihil-obstat-and-imprimatur/

Comment: I'll change the example to something that requires Nihil Obstat and Imprimatur...

Comment: My understanding is that the Nihil Obstat is obtained from someone appointed for that purpose by the bishop who afterward gives the Imprimatur.  But I don't know whether you can get the Imprimatur from just any bishop or whether it has to be a bishop who has jurisdiction over you.

Comment: Great question as I am ready to get my first Nihil Obstat and Imprimatur in the coming year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain an "Imprimi Potest," an "Nihil Obstat," or an "Imprimatur" one has to go through one's ordinary (local bishop).

[image: Nihil Obstat and Imprimatur]

[The “Nihil Obstat” and “Imprimatur"](http://taylormarshall.com/2010/10/what-do-nihil-obstat-and-imprimatur.html)

> The Church, given teaching authority by Christ and as the conduit for fullness of Truth on this earth, has the obligation to preserve Her sheep from deviations from the Truth and to guarantee them the "objective possibility of professing the true faith without error" (Catechism, No. 890). Because of this, the Bishops will look at books published by Catholics on Catholic matters in their dioceses, giving them their "okay" if nothing therein is found to be contrary to the Faith (relevant Canon Law: "Title IV: The Means of Social Communication," ¶ 822-832)
>
> **The procedure works like this**: when a Catholic writes a book on faith, morals, theology, liturgy, books on prayer, editions of Sacred Scripture, etc., he will submit his manuscript to his diocese's Censor. If the Censor finds no problem with it, he will give it his stamp, which reads "**Nihil Obstat**," or "nothing stands in the way." He then sends it to the Bishop for his review. If the Bishop finds nothing objectionable, he gives the book his "**Imprimatur**" which means, "let it be printed."
>
> If the Catholic writing the book is a member of a religious order, the manuscript is first sent to his religious superior before it is sent to the Censor and Bishop. If the religious superior finds no impediment to publication, he will give the book his stamp of "**Imprimi Potest**," which means "it can be printed."
>
> Nowadays, after the Imprimatur, you might see these words:
>
> The "Nihil Obstat" and "Imprimatur" are official declarations that a book or pamphlet is free of doctrinal or moral error. No implication is contained therein that those who have granted the Nihil Obstat and the Imprimatur agree with the content, opinions or statements expressed.

```
 Religious Superior's stamp:   IMPRIMI POTEST   "it can be printed" 

             Censor's stamp:   NIHIL OBSTAT     "nothing stands in the way" 

             Bishop's stamp:   IMPRIMATUR       "let it be printed"
```

**Addendum**: The author of a book or owner of the copyright/patent must approach the local bishop for publishing Catholic doctrinal books or apps and so on before going to a publisher or company.

Comment: So in the question’s case, it means the local bishop/ordinary of the company where the app is developed?